# Error:scalac: bad option: -P (IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

After upgrade to **IntelliJ IDEA 14.1** a project compilation stuck with an error message:

**Error:scalac: bad option: -P:/Users//.m2/repository/org/scalamacros/paradise_2.10.4/2.1.0-M1/paradise_2.10.4-2.1.0-M1.jar**

There is an additional parameter for scala compiler in:

```
Preferences 
 -> Build, Execution, Deployment 
    -> Compiler
       -> Scala compiler
          -> Additional compiler options = <some parameters>
```

So, now you know from where the parameter comes from and it's up to you to decide should you remove/change for something else or not.

Hope it saved you time ;-)

Comment: it looks like you answered your own question (which is great), however you should post the answer below (check the "Answer you own question" box) and accept it later

Comment: at this point (now that the question is already posted) you should see a black button at the bottom of the page labeled "Answer Your Question"

Comment: This only works if you no longer use macro-paradise plugin. (In which case the option is useless) but if you do, every time you refresh you will see such option being regenerated. So its still an incomplete solution

Comment: You are right. I'm still facing with that problem. If you know how to solve it completely please let us know. That's annoying :-(

Comment: Nothing is there in my Additional compiler options, still i am getting the issue like Error:scala: bad option: '-target:jvm-1.8' . How can your answer helps me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change the scala compiler parameters to

```
-Xplugin:/your/user/home/.m2/repository/org/scalamacros/paradise_2.10.4/2.0.1/paradise_2.10.4-2.0.1.jar
```

(of course giving your valid home folder) in

```
Preferences 
 -> Build, Execution, Deployment 
    -> Compiler
       -> Scala compiler
          -> Additional compiler options = <some parameters>
```

(as said in the question)

This solves the problem for me. It seems the `-P` flag is for specifying a plugin option while `-Xplugin` is for setting a plugin file location.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it wasn't work - but i solved this problem!
Delete scala_compiler.xml in .ieda dir.
And it works fine!

Maybe someone will find this useful

Comment: This would also disable compiler plugins in Idea builds.

Comment: I had a related error (`bad option: -target:jvm-17`) and this answer pointed me to the issue. It was set in this file

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same exact problem and found a permanent solution in IntelliJ.

I'm using IDEA 16.1,and a Scala-sbt based project. I know the original question seems to be related to a maven project, but just in case you're using SBT (and Scala), here you are:

in the build.sbt, it is needed to add the following:

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

Please notice the `cross CrossVersion.full`. If you try to use a specific version (e.g. `paradise_2.11.7`), then it will **not work**.

In addition to the compiler plugin (which is enough for SBT), then you need to add the next dependency in order to compile/run your code from IDEA:

```
"org.scalamacros" % "paradise" % "2.1.0" cross CrossVersion.full
```

P.S.: I put nothing in the IDEA preferences